# In this context, what exactly does $('id').on('click', this.method.bind(this)) do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

[Here is the app I'm referring to:](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nervous-whimsey?path=public/js/app.js:73:29)

I am trying to fundamentally understand the bind method in Javascript.

My understanding when I play around with it in the console is that bind returns a copy of the function, with "this" bound to whatever you pass into bind.

```
function logThis(){
  console.log(this)
}
logThis.bind({today: 'Tuesday'})
//Will return a copy of the logThis function, with 'this' set to the 
{today:'Tuesday'} object. The code does not run right away though.

var explicitlyLogThis = logThis.bind({today: 'Tuesday'});
explicitlyLogThis(); //This will run the code and display the {today: 'Tuesday'} object to the console.
```

This is my understanding so far. I understand that to actually run this new function that has 'this' explicitly bound using the bind method, you need to set it to a variable and then run it.

I see a contradiction when I look at the app in the above link. If you look at the bindEvents method on line 56, we have .on('keyup', this.create.bind(this)). I understand that we have to set 'this' to App when we run the create method because jQuery defaults to setting 'this' to the jQuery object itself. So this line is actually the same as: $('#new-todo').on('keyup', App.create.bind(App)).

That isn't where my confusion is. My question is:

How exactly are these copies of the functions with 'this' set to App actually being called? The app does not set them to a variable and then call that variable the way I had to when I was working in the console.

It just invokes the bound functions directly as soon as an event occurs on one of the jQuery elements. But I thought writing it this way would just return a copy of the function, and not run the function itself, if I am basing my assumptions on what I have figured out in the code I wrote above. I thought in order to invoke the function immediately, you would need to use call or apply.

I also realize that the app runs the bindEvents method when it starts (see line 46). So I understand that when you start the app, copies of the various functions are created with the correct 'this' bound to the functions. But...when/how do they actually get invoked without assigning them to variables? How are these copies accessed?

I think I have a flawed understanding of the bind method, so I would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: So the logThis.bind({today: 'Tuesday'}) returns a copy of itself automatically. It's weird because it doesn't return the content inside the function itself, so while I realize it isn't an error, it also isn't running normally either until I call it separately.

Comment: Sorry the last message was for a different question post.  But for your question the bound function is saved internally (in the native browser code) and called later during the event loop. jQuery's `on()` calls the native `addEventListener()` method which adds the passed function to a list. Each callback in the list will get executed by the event loop mechanism

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you understand `bind` well enough. Perhaps there is some confusion with passing anonymous functions. As you know calling bind returns a new function and this can optionally be stored as a variable or passed as a function argument.

In the example below btn1 accepts a bound function as you've seen. This could also be written in a more long hand fashion with btn2. They're identical. btn3 doesn't receive a bound function, when its clicked its context is the button element, `this` looses all visibility of `MagicalApp` fucntions.

```html
<button id="example1">button one bound</button>
<button id="example2">button one bound</button>
<button id="example3">button two unbound</button>
<script>
  class MagicalApp {
    add() {
      console.log('this could do addition');
    }
  }

  const app = new MagicalApp();

  function contextOfEvent(event) {
    console.log('contextSensitive', this.add)
  }

  const btn1 = document.querySelector("#example1");
  btn1.addEventListener('click', contextOfEvent.bind(app));

  const btn2 = document.querySelector("#example2");
  const btn2ClickHandler = contextOfEvent.bind(app)
  btn2.addEventListener('click', btn2ClickHandler);

  const btn3 = document.querySelector("#example3");
  btn3.addEventListener('click', contextOfEvent);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I may ask a few more questions to clarify:

1) You said, "Perhaps there is some confusion with passing anonymous functions." Which function is anonymous here? We have named contextOfEvent and the add() function. Is the anonymous function the addEventListener method? In that case, it seems more like we are passing things into it, not that it is being passed itself.

2) So we are passing contextOfEvent.bind(app) into addEventListener as a function argument? 

Appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, addEventListener accepts a function argument. Using `btn2ClickHandler` as the argument is a named function. Using `contextOfEvent.bind(app)` is a copy of `contextOfEvent` or an anonymous function.